# Disk goes to sleep a lot

Tags: linux, hard-drive, sleep, power-management

Running PopOS-20 /ubuntu based. This is a secondary box I use for backups etc.

I have a 750GB HD. What's weird with that one, and something I have never had with any disk before, is that it goes to some sleep state very often and very soon.

I usually log in via sshd, then, after I have done something, I come back later, say 1 minute, and typing has a lot of delayed response. I can hear the HD spinning up, and when at full, the shell becomes responsive again.

Why could that be? Can I improve that? Some power management thing? I recall that before recently upgrading to PopOS, I had some older distro running, but I had the same behavior, so it seems not to be OS specific.

I vaguely recall having done some power management config on the disk many years ago. Any suggestion how I can clear that? I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks. It's a Seagate

Answer (score 2):

`hdparm -B 255 /dev/sda` completely disables power management. I actually did

`hdparm -B 250 /dev/sda` and it is at least muuch better. Not sure I want to disable completely.

I had probably run `hdparm -B 127 /dev/sda` way back a couple of years myself.